# ASP.NET - Trying to output variable into jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to simply grab the value of `callid`, if defined within the url and set it to a checked box (this is the id of the `<input type="checkbox" />`).  So if this is defined, it should check the box by default.

Here's what I'm using, but am getting error on the page:

```
<%
Dim CallId
CallId = Request.QueryString("callid")
If Callid <> "" Then %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#<% CallId %>").prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
<% End If %>
```

The Error points to this bit:  `$("#<% CallId %>")` Saying that CallId is not an expression.

How do I set `CallId` value inside of this jQuery tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
 $("#<%= CallId %>").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: This worked.  I needed to change the url to use:  `&`, not `?`.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the JS way, by the answers said. But this isn't pragmatic, it doesn't make sense to me. What stops you from doing it the .NET way and doing it server-side?

Such as:

```
<%
Dim CallId
CallId = Request.QueryString("callid")
If CallId <> "" Then
    Dim checkBox = this.FindControl(CallId) As CheckBox
    If checkBox IsNot Nothing
       checkBox.Checked = True
    End If
End If
%>
```

Comment: This looks much better, but the Expression is never true.  I put the callid value in there, the end of the url looks like this: `form.aspx?id=2846?callid=ID130604`, `ID130604` is the id value of the `input` element, but it never gets checked, why?

Comment: Updated answer - there was a small "i" on the If statement, it should have been CallId. You should also put a breakpoint on the If statement to see what CallId is being set to and if it's getting to the Checked statement. Note that the CallId in the If statement is your .NET CheckBox element ID.

Comment: Updated answer with FindControl method as this has to be dynamic.

Comment: I have put this into the `<head>` tag of the document, is that right?  Or should it go someplace else?

Comment: It should go in your code-behind file, ideally, but anywhere on the page is fine as it's server-side code.

Comment: I get Compilation error on this code:  `Dim checkBox = this.FindControl(CallId) As CheckBox`, says End of Statement Expected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a C# guy rather than VB, I think you can just say Dim checkBox As CheckBox = this.FindControl(CallId)

Comment: Now I get `Name this is Not declared`

Comment: Not sure on the VB.NET equivalent... replace this with Me?

Comment: I'm getting the End of Statement Expected error again now on this line:  `Dim checkBox = Me.FindControl(CallId) As CheckBox`

Comment: If I remove the `As CheckBox` at the end of the line, the page just loads, but never checks the checkbox.

Comment: Does it get into the If statement when you debug it?

Comment: No, but I found out the problem, it needs to use `&` not `?` within the URL.  Thanks anyways, but have decided to use the jQuery approach!

Answer (score 0):

Try this notation `<%= CallId %>`

Comment: Ok, so the error went away, but the Expression doesn't work, cause it shows nothing, when I put `callid` within the URL